# User profile shows "Earlier this month" for posts one year ago on Android app

Tags: bug, profile-page, android-app

I was checking a user profile (not mine) on the Android app v1.0.51, and noticed that posts from a year ago were tagged as "Earlier this month". When I checked such a post, I saw they were from December 2013.

It doesn't really matter which users feed I was checking in the app, any profile which goes 1 year back and has an activity in the Profile will show Earlier this month for last year February for example (I take February because it is February at the moment)

[image: user profile displaying the bug]

This bug still remains in the current version of the android app, as can be seen from the screenshot below (having post from June 2016 and *earlier this month* from may 2016 (with version 1.0.89)

[image]

Comment: Sorry to bother, but it would be better if you could provide the user profile link, or the screenshot to complete the bug report. I found it difficult to reproduce this bug with random users' feed.

Comment: @AndrewT. Well, then take my profile from the mobile app and search my activity in februari 2015, this one will show earlier this month. I have just tested in on your profile and it seems to be still an actual problem. I'm not sure about your edit though, I added a screenshot from your profile just to demonstrate the bug

Comment: Ah, I see, so it's when the posts are *exactly* a year old (same month from now, years ago), thanks for clarifying! I thought the issue with the post's age was arbitrary, not exact.